# Data table specific column filter with multi select drop down

Tags: datatables

I have seen this possibility in the Datatable API for the specific column filtering with Drop down.

Ref: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

But for me, its different, I need to do the same with multi-select drop down. So the datatable should show the results accordingly.

So as in the above link, I can not able to select two offices "Tokyo and London". I had implemented the coding with multi-select plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but the datatable takes only one option.

Is that possible? If so can you please help on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After long search, I found a solution for this. Actually it was very simple. Below is my fix for this option.

There was already an option to search for specific column vise as per the below link,

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

```
      // DataTable
       var table = $('#example').DataTable();
       
       // 2 is column id 
       // "India" is search string
       table.column( 2 ).search( 'India' ).draw(); 
   
   So the above one will search for "India" in a specific column "2" (Say like "Country" column)
   
   Here i need an ability to search for more than one country like "India, Japan etc.,"
   
   So the code will be as follows,
   
           // DataTable
           var table = $('#example').DataTable();
           
           // 2 is column id 
           // "India|Japan|Spain" is search string
           table.column( 2 ).search( 'India|Japan|Spain', true, false ).draw();
```

> Updated: We need to add two more parameters in the "search()"
> function.

```
        
        search(val_1,val_2,val_3)
        
        where,
        val_1 is search string with "|" symbol separated. So it contains regular express chars as per the example. 
        val_2 is true (To enable regular express in the search)
        val_3 is false (To disable smart search. default is true)
```

Ref: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

So I have just added a "pipe" symbol between the search strings.

Comment: @Nishant Updated the answer. Please add true and false as 2nd and 3rd parameters respectively in your search function to enable regular expression.

Comment: I have one drop down below the column of the data tables, i want to select multiple vales and once select those the search should work with these new values. I saw your answer here, but not sure how to map the selected drop down vale to the search function. Can you please help me out on this. If you want to know details about my question here is the link .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328602/how-to-select-multiple-values-in-a-drop-down-data-tables?noredirect=1#comment69860541_41328602