# how to select multiple values in a drop down Data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to jquery and Data tables. I have a drop down when user select one value it will search the data and draw a table.This search and drawing a table both are default properties of data tables.  Now i want the user can select multiple value.

And based on the multiple selection the search should happen.I did lot of search on this but didn't get any thing. Any help will be appreciate !!

In this image i have selected one value from drop down and based on that two entries are populating on table. now i want to select multiple values here in this drop down , may be using check box after that need the search should work with both selected entries. 
[image]

Comment: you means, attribute to select as multiple ?

Comment: @V for Vendetta .Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this . I am posting this answer because it may be help some one.

jQuery MultiSelect is a jQuery plugin that turns a multiselect list into a nice dropdown list with checkboxes. This plugin is easy to use and very useful in web form. You need to use two library called jquery.multiselect.css and jquery.multiselect.js. if you will search examples of multi select using J query you will find many links and that will work perfect with your data tables. For search option You need to pass multiple value to the function which is constructing your data tables. See below link for details.

http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/

Comment: could you please share any example of passing multiple value to the function. I tried, but it doesn't work. If you want to know details about my question here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751650/data-table-specific-column-filter-with-multi-select-drop-down-values