# Jquery DataTable filter should be in checkbox format and multiple parameters should be chosen

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable filter, instead of a filter at the column, I want my filter to be in the form of multiple checkboxes, 
so far the code I have written is as follows:
HTML:

```
div class="dropdown">
            <p class="filter-text">Fruits</p>
                <select name="fruit" multiple id="fruit">
                    <option value="AP">apple</option>
                    <option value="MN">mango</option>

                </select>
            </div>
```

In my data table I am doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table =  $('#example').DataTable();

     $('#fruit).on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );
```

But this code replaces only one value, for example if I choose apple, it will select apple and wen I also click on mango it shows mango in the table.
what I want is for it to show both apple and mango on checking both of them.
Please help me with it

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479868/data-table-specific-column-filter-with-multi-select-drop-down ?

Comment: Here you got a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fhmhn2p8/

Comment: It still doesn't work when multiple options are selected right

Comment: If i want to deselect all the checkboxes and draw empty table, it is redrawing the whole table and showing it. How do i correct it